# Error : <circle> attribute <cx> Expected length NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
 d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle.jongno")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "jongno")
.attr("r", 5)
.attr("cx", function (d) { return xScale(d.quarter) })
.attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.jongno) })
.style("fill", "black")
```

Please help me. Why can't the circle be printed? It's so hard to do a project alone.
The status of the csv file is like this.
quarter = {1, 2, 3, 4}, jongno = {46.9, 45.8, 44.8, 43.9}

Comment: `xScale(d.quarter)` is not returning a number but you have not shown the how you define the scale function, or shown what you are passing to it (when you log `data` do you get an array of objects, each with a property `quarter` and `jongno`? - what you have shared is neither a csv nor a data array). If you add these details, an answer will be much more possible.

Comment: Can you share with us more detaild about the xScale?

Comment: Post the `xScale` code. Is it a `scaleBand ` ?